# Pygame time control

Tags: python, time, pygame

I've been thinking in pygame how can i control time.
Namely, when an if-statement is True , i want it True just for some seconds, 
Which is the best pygame.time-object to use?
Example

```
if p.rect.left < self.rect.centerx < p.rect.right and self.rect.bottom >= 560:
            self.kill()

            p.image.fill(red)
```

This is a ball bounce-collision and whenever this statement is True i want it to stay True just for an amount of time. How can I do that? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using the function `pygame.time.get_ticks()`?

`pygame.time.get_ticks()` outputs the current tick number, a tick is represented in milliseconds.

it is used like this:

```
begin = pygame.time.get_ticks()

while pygame_loop:
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if time_now-begin > 1000:
        begin=pygame.time.get_ticks()
        statement = True
```

and your code will look like this:

```
timeout = 1000
last_true = -timeout

if (p.rect.left < self.rect.centerx < p.rect.right and self.rect.bottom >= 560):
    last_true = pygame.time.get_ticks()

if pygame.time.get_ticks() < last_true + timeout:
    self.kill()
    p.image.fill(red)
```

Comment: I'd -1 this for bumping if I was heartless

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. Instead of simply checking if your statement evalueate to `True`, it checks if it's been evaluated to `True` within the last certain period of time that you specify. See [Time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time).

```
import time

%this is the time in seconds you wish the loop to be treated as true
timeout = 1.0 
last_true = -timeout

if (p.rect.left < self.rect.centerx < p.rect.right and self.rect.bottom >= 560):
    last_true = time.time()

if time.time() < last_true + timeout:
    self.kill()
    p.image.fill(red)
```

Comment: you should not use time to count seconds in pygame but `pygame.time`

Comment: @Liam If you're going to leave that comment, would you mind explaining why?

Comment: a pygame game can lag and could not follow the system time and a `time.time` second can be inaccurate in game. `pygame.time` is more accurate.